# How to declare a class that contains a field with generic type in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin I have a data class.

```
data class APIResponse<out T>(val status: String, val code: Int, val message: String, val data: T?)
```

I want to declare another class to include this:

```
class APIError(message: String, response: APIResponse) : Exception(message) {}
```

but Kotlin is giving error: One type argument expected for class APIResponse defined in com.mypackagename

In Java I can do this:

```
class APIError extends Exception {

    APIResponse response;

    public APIError(String message, APIResponse response) {
        super(message);
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

How can I convert the code to Kotlin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have in your Java is a *raw type*.  In the section on [star-projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections), the Kotlin documentation says:

> Note: star-projections are very much like Java's raw types, but safe.

They describe their use-case:

> Sometimes you want to say that you know nothing about the type argument, but still want to use it in a safe way. The safe way here is to define such a projection of the generic type, that every concrete instantiation of that generic type would be a subtype of that projection.

Your `APIError` class therefore becomes:

```
class APIError(message: String, val response: APIResponse<*>) : Exception(message) {}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have not yet tried it but I think this should work.